# Python finding next word permutation with function generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

Learning how to use function generators in Python I practiced with the following code that finds the next permutation of a word and then uses this new word as input for the next one until there are no further permutations. So for example 'dbac' is followed by 'dacb' followed by 'dabc' and so on.

Basically two questions: 1) the use of two times `break` to stop the two for-loops is there a better way to break out of the loops, and 2) the final part `try: return finally: StopIteration` is this a proper construction?

```
def nextperm(word):

    stoploop = True
    while stoploop:
        wordlist = [*word]
        length = len(wordlist)-1
        stoploop = False
        for index_1 in range(length-1, -1, -1):
            for index_2 in range(length, index_1-1, -1):
                if wordlist[index_2] < wordlist[index_1]:
                    wordlist[index_2], wordlist[index_1] = wordlist[index_1], wordlist[index_2]
                    _first = wordlist[0:index_1+1]
                    _second = wordlist[-1:index_1:-1]
                    wordlist = _first + _second
                    word = ''.join(wordlist)
                    stoploop = True
                    yield word
                    break
            if stoploop:
                break

    try:
        return print('no further permutation possible')
    finally:
        raise StopIteration
```

so if you do:

```
for i, word in enumerate(nextperm('dcba')):
    print(f'{i:2}, {word}')
```

output is:

```
 0, dcab
 1, dbca
 2, dbac
 3, dacb
 4, dabc
 5, cdba
 6, cdab
 7, cbda
 8, cbad
 9, cadb
10, cabd
11, bdca
12, bdac
13, bcda
14, bcad
15, badc
16, bacd
17, adcb
18, adbc
19, acdb
20, acbd
21, abdc
22, abcd
no further permutation possible
```

Comment: is the order of permutations important? And why not just use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: yes the order is important as the result of the generator should produce the next permutation so next(nextperm('adbc')) gives 'acdb'

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Review

1. The name `nextperm` is misleading as (i) it generates permutations that *precede* its argument; (ii) it generates multiple permutations, not just one. So a name like `preceding_permutations` would be clearer.
2. There is no need for `try: ... finally:` or `raise StopIteration` or `return`. If we try to get additional values from a generator that has finished, then Python automatically raises `StopIteration`. For example:

   ```
   >>> def generator():
   ...     yield 1
   >>> g = generator()
   >>> next(g)
   1
   >>> next(g)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   StopIteration
   ```
3. It's not necessary to convert `word` to a list on each iteration of the `while` loop, because on subsequent iterations we already have this list in the variable `wordlist`.
4. All the permutations are the same length, so it is not necessary to reassign `length` on each loop.
5. This loop goes all the way down to `index_1`:

   ```
   for index_2 in range(length, index_1-1, -1):
   ```

   But when `index_2 == index_1`, the condition `wordlist[index_2] < wordlist[index_1]` can never be true. So this iteration is wasted. It would be better to write the second loop like this:

   ```
   for index_2 in range(length, index_1, -1):
   ```
6. Reversed ranges are quite tricky to reason about, and this kind of mistake is easy to make, so we should consider using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) instead to make things simpler:

   ```
   for index_2 in reversed(range(index_1 + 1, length + 1)):
   ```

   (And similarly for `index_1`.)
7. When I read the name "length", I expect this to be the length of the word, not the length of the word minus one. So it would be easier to follow the logic if we had `length = len(wordlist)`, and adjusted the ranges accordingly.
8. The code reverses the last part of `wordlist`, leaving the first part unchanged:

   ```
   _first = wordlist[0:index_1+1]
   _second = wordlist[-1:index_1:-1]
   wordlist = _first + _second
   ```

   It would make sense to implement this using a [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

   ```
   wordlist[index_1 + 1:] = reversed(wordlist[index_1 + 1:])
   ```

   This has several advantages: we avoid having to take the slice for the first part of the list, we reuse the memory in `wordlist`, and the use of [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) makes it clear what is happenig and reduces the risk of getting the slice indexes wrong.
9. The names `index_1` and `index_2` are used a lot: it would shorten the code and make it easier to read if we had names like `i` and `j`.
10. The `stoploop` logic can be removed if we introduce a local function that generates pairs of indexes:

    ```
    def indexes():
        for i in reversed(range(length - 1)):
            for j in reversed(range(i + 1, length)):
                yield i, j
    ```

    Now the two loops over the indexes can be combined into one:

    ```
    for i, j in indexes():
    ```

    and since we now have a single loop, we can break out of it using `break`, with no need for `stoploop`.

#### 2. Revised code

```
def preceding_permutations(word):
    """Generate the permutations of word that precede it, in reverse
    lexicographical order.

    >>> ' '.join(preceding_permutations('bdca'))
    'bdac bcda bcad badc bacd adcb adbc acdb acbd abdc abcd'

    """
    word = list(word)
    length = len(word)
    def indexes():
        for i in reversed(range(length - 1)):
            for j in reversed(range(i + 1, length)):
                yield i, j
    while True:
        for i, j in indexes():
            if word[j] < word[i]:
                word[j], word[i] = word[i], word[j]
                word[i + 1:] = reversed(word[i + 1:])
                yield ''.join(word)
                break
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth, some very useful tips and insides I will play around with. Especially the idea of generating the indices and combining them!